# Associating two database tables which have ForeignKey relation in models.py in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have problem about django template-db query relationship.

For example, I created two tables in db (e.g. Menu & Submenu). Submenu, as you can guess, has a ForeignKey relationship with Menu.

On the template side how can Ido db-query according to this relationship. I want to have a link for Menu such as:

```
{% for menu in menu_list %}
<li>menu.title</li>
   # And here put each Submenu which has ForeignKey relation with specific Menu
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If ozan's suggestion doesn't work, please show your model definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `{% for submenu in menu.submenu_set.all %}{# do something #}{% endfor %}`.

You should really read [the relevant docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) before asking a question like this.

Comment: Well, I read it. But couldn't figure out how to edit on views. btw, your suggestion doesn't work. thanks anyway;)

Comment: What does it have to do with views? If that didn't work, I'm guessing you've set a related_name on the foreign key to Menu, in which case you need to use that instead of submenu_set.